# Install PyInstaller on MSYS2 MinGW

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pygobject

I want to install `PyInstaller` on `MinGW` but installing with `pip` fails with an error.
`distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module`
How do I install it correctly? If this is not possible, what other options do I have? I am trying to build a Python GTK+3 application on Windows from the Linux version.

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest version of `setuptools`? Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python 3.7.1. How do I install the latest version? pip3 says it's up to date (40.5.0)

Comment: I'm not too sure what the issue is. Have you tried manually installing it? Like downloading the source `tar.gz` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/#files), unzipping it, and running `python3 setup.py install`.

Comment: that seems to have worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear. I added a more descriptive answer below for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ussually if a pip install doesn't work, I always revert to the manual installation.

**Steps:**

1. Download the source `PyInstaller-3.4.tar.gz` file from [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/#files).
2. Navigate to your Downloads folder and unzip the file with `tar xf PyInstaller-3.4.tar.gz`. If your using Windows, you can use *7zip* or something.
3. `cd` into `PyInstaller-3.4` and run `python3 setup.py install`. Using `python` or `python3` depends on how you've set up Python on your operating system.

This will install the `PyInstaller` module in the same way as pip, just takes some extra steps to perform.

Comment: Even though I have it installed now, the executables produced doesn't actually work. The output it `Error loading Python DLL 'C:\msys64\home\zandimna\build\a\libpython3.7m.dll'.
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.` 
EDIT: I can use it with --onefile.

Comment: @ShaoyuTseng I always run `pyinstaller --onfile --noconsole` to product a single executable with no console window showing up in the background.